# Typescript: Map object onto another using generics

Tags: typescript, function, generics, bind

I am building a system in typescript where there are two object types: *Actions* and *ExtendedActions*. They are both supposed to share the same property names, and each property should be a function.

The idea is that the system should automatically generate Actions by taking ExtendedActions and binding to the first parameter of each member function.

I created a minimal example (that doesn't work).

```
function createId() {
  return 'test'
}

interface Actions {
  setName: (name: string) => void
  setTitle: (title: string) => void
}

/**
 * ExtendedActions is identical to Actions, except
 * that each function has an additional id parameter:
 */
type AddArg<F> = F extends (...args: infer P) => infer R
  ? (id: string, ...args: P) => R
  : never

type ExtendedActions = {
  [P in keyof Actions]: AddArg<Actions[P]>
}

// Instantiate ExtendedActions.
const myExtendedActions: ExtendedActions = {
  setName: (id: string, name: string) => {
    //
  },
  setTitle: (id: string, title: string) => {
    //
  },
}

/**
 * (Doesn't work) Generically instantiate Actions by binding the id parameter from ExtendedActions.
 */
function generateActions<TExtendedActions, TActions>(
  extendedActions: TExtendedActions
): TActions {
  const id: string = createId()

  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(extendedActions).map((name: string) => {
      return [name, extendedActions[name].bind(id)]
    })
  ) as TActions
}

// Instantiate Actions.
const myActions = generateActions<ExtendedActions, Actions>(
  myExtendedActions
)
```

The current code complains that I can't access the property extendedActions[name]:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.  TS7053`

However, even if that would work, the approach above is not sufficient, since
Object.fromEntries() just creates a dynamic object that needs to be cast into the type TActions without losing the type information;

`Conversion of type '{ [k: string]: ***; }' to type 'TActions' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. 'TActions' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ [k: string]: ***; }'.  TS2352`

Are there any ways of achieving this kind of generic behavior?

Comment: I don't really get the requirement but it sound to me that you rather need composition instead of inheritance and generics. You could define the ExtendedAction to have a constructor like `constructor(id:string, action:Action){}` assuming that Action is not an interface anymore.